# Equivalent Relational Algebra statement for a given SQL query

Tags: sql, relational-database, relational-algebra

The following SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a1,a2,a3.....an
FROM   R1,R2,R3......Rm
Where P
(P is any predicate)
```

I want to know what could possibly be its equivalent Relational Algebra. I think it might be something like this:
`πa1,a2,a3...an(σP(R1 U R2 U R3 ....U Rm)`.
But again I am not sure whether I am correct. Can anyone help me with its correct equivalent in Relational Algebra?

Comment: Hi. This can't be answered (without guessing) unless you 1. Give a reference to what specific RA (& associated query language) you are told to use. They differ by what operators & arguments (& predicates) are allowed & even what a relation is. 2. Explain what "equivalent" means. Same result? Some notion of parallel structure?

Answer (score 1):

Take a good look in SQL what the commas stand for in the FROM clause, and then take a good look at what U (I suppose UNION ?) does in algebra.

Answer (score 0):

The commas in the FROM clause of an SQL expression represent the cross product.

So the equivalent relational algebra expression is:

```
π a1,a2,a3...an (σ P (R1 x R2 x ... x Rm))
```